# こちらの記事を参考にdynamodbインポートを試みているのですがうまくいきません。

Tags: aws, amazon-dynamodb

こちらの記事を参考にdynamodbインポートを試みているのですがうまくいきません。

Amazon DynamoDB への CSV 一括取り込みの実装
https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/news/implementing-bulk-csv-ingestion-to-amazon-dynamodb/

DynamoDB、Amazon S3、Lambda、および AWS CloudFormation にアクセスできる IAM ユーザー。

記事の内容はs3にcsvが入ったら、それをトリガーとしてcsvをdynamodbにインポートさせるlambdaを動かす
cloudfomationスタックを作るものと記憶しています。

#### dynamoDBの構成

テーブル名   test
プライマリパーティションキー  tag (文字列)
プライマリソートキー  keyword (文字列)

#### 挿入csvの構成

```
hoge1,fuga1
hoge2,fuga2
hoge3,fuga3
hoge4,fuga4
hoge5,fuga5
hoge6,fuga6
hoge7,fuga7
hoge8,fuga8
hoge9,fuga9
hoge10,fuga10
```

手順としてfloudfomationに入り

1.スタックの作成をクリック

前提条件 - テンプレートの準備：
テンプレートの準備完了を選択

テンプレートの指定：
テンプレートファイルのアップロードを選択、
テンプレートには記事から入れるgithubにあるテンプレートを選択

2.スタックの詳細を指定

スタックの名前：csv-to-dynamodb

パラメータ
bucketname「dynamo-imp-0101」

dynamodbtablename[test]
↑サンプルに合うフォーマットで作成したテーブル

filename[test.csv]
↑サンプルファイルの上から２行のみ使用

3.スタックオプションの設定

アクセス許可:
以下のロールを使用

使用付与ロール：
s3fullaccess
DynamoDBfullaccess
Lambdafullaccess
CloudFormationfullaccess

この設定でスタックを作成しても、すぐにcloudfomationに
×マークがついてしまいます。

考えられるエラーでIAMの設定が適してない為、処理が継続しないことが
考えられます、ただし、十分にロールの権限を付与しているため
どのような権限を付与すればよいかわかりません。

「csvファイル名やテーブル名、バケット名が間違ってないか」
「csvとテーブルのフォーマット間違ってないか」
については調べてつぶしています。

イベントログはこちらになります。

```
2020-06-26 12:14:59 UTC+0900    testfile    ROLLBACK_COMPLETE   -
2020-06-26 12:14:58 UTC+0900    LambdaRole  DELETE_COMPLETE -
2020-06-26 12:14:56 UTC+0900    DynamoDBTable   DELETE_COMPLETE -
2020-06-26 12:14:56 UTC+0900    LambdaRole  DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2020-06-26 12:14:49 UTC+0900    testfile    ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS    The following resource(s) failed to create: [DynamoDBTable, LambdaRole]. . Rollback requested by user.
2020-06-26 12:14:48 UTC+0900    LambdaRole  CREATE_FAILED   Resource creation cancelled
2020-06-26 12:14:47 UTC+0900    LambdaRole  CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2020-06-26 12:14:47 UTC+0900    DynamoDBTable   CREATE_FAILED   testfile already exists in stack arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-northeast-1:671527041604:stack/xxx/b4e28760-b52a-11ea-9d7b-06c1e14cac70
```

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Metadata": {

    },
    "Parameters" : {
        "BucketName": {
            "Description": "Name of the S3 bucket you will deploy the CSV file to",
            "Type": "String",
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid bucket name."
        },
        "FileName": {
            "Description": "Name of the S3 file (including suffix)",
            "Type": "String",
            "ConstraintDescription": "Valid S3 file name."
        },
        "DynamoDBTableName": {
            "Description": "Name of the dynamoDB table you will use",
            "Type": "String",
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid dynamoDB name."
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "DynamoDBTable":{
            "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
            "Properties":{
                "TableName": {"Ref" : "test"},
                "BillingMode": "PAY_PER_REQUEST",
                "AttributeDefinitions":[
                    {
                        "AttributeName": "uuid",
                        "AttributeType": "S"
                    }
                ],
                "KeySchema":[
                    {
                        "AttributeName": "uuid",
                        "KeyType": "HASH"
                    }
                ],
                "Tags":[
                    {
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": {"Ref" : "test"}
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "LambdaRole" : {
          "Type" : "AWS::IAM::Role",
          "Properties" : {
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
              "Version" : "2012-10-17",
              "Statement" : [
                {
                  "Effect" : "Allow",
                  "Principal" : {
                    "Service" : ["lambda.amazonaws.com","s3.amazonaws.com"]
                  },
                  "Action" : [
                    "sts:AssumeRole"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "Path" : "/",
            "ManagedPolicyArns":["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole","arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaInvocation-DynamoDB","arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess"],
            "Policies": [{
                             "PolicyName": "policyname",
                             "PolicyDocument": {
                                       "Version": "2012-10-17",
                                       "Statement": [{
                                    "Effect": "Allow",
                                                "Resource": "*",
                                                  "Action": [
                                                              "dynamodb:PutItem",
                                                              "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem"
                                                  ]
                                      }]
                             }
                    }]
          }
       },
        "CsvToDDBLambdaFunction": {
            "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
            "Properties": {
                "Handler": "index.lambda_handler",
                "Role": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "LambdaRole",
                        "Arn"
                    ]
                },
                "Code": {
                    "ZipFile": {
                        "Fn::Join": [
                            "\n",
                            [
                                "import json",
                                "import boto3",
                                "import os",
                                "import csv",
                                "import codecs",
                                "import sys",
                                "",
                                "s3 = boto3.resource('s3')",
                                "dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')",
                                "",
                                "bucket = os.environ['bucket']",
                                "key = os.environ['key']",
                                "tableName = os.environ['table']",
                                "",
                                "def lambda_handler(event, context):",
                                "",  
                                "",
                                "   #get() does not store in memory",
                                "   try:",
                                "       obj = s3.Object(bucket, key).get()['Body']",
                                "   except:",
                                "       print(\"S3 Object could not be opened. Check environment variable. \")",
                                "   try:",
                                "       table = dynamodb.Table(tableName)",
                                "   except:",
                                "       print(\"Error loading DynamoDB table. Check if table was created correctly and environment variable.\")",
                                "",
                                "   batch_size = 100",
                                "   batch = []",
                                "",
                                "   #DictReader is a generator; not stored in memory",
                                "   for row in csv.DictReader(codecs.getreader('utf-8')(obj)):",
                                "      if len(batch) >= batch_size:",
                                "         write_to_dynamo(batch)",
                                "         batch.clear()",
                                "",
                                "      batch.append(row)",
                                "",
                                "   if batch:",
                                "      write_to_dynamo(batch)",
                                "",
                                "   return {",
                                "      'statusCode': 200,",
                                "      'body': json.dumps('Uploaded to DynamoDB Table')",
                                "   }",
                                "",
                                "",    
                                "def write_to_dynamo(rows):",
                                "   try:",
                                "      table = dynamodb.Table(tableName)",
                                "   except:",
                                "      print(\"Error loading DynamoDB table. Check if table was created correctly and environment variable.\")",
                                "",
                                "   try:",
                                "      with table.batch_writer() as batch:",
                                "         for i in range(len(rows)):",
                                "            batch.put_item(",
                                "               Item=rows[i]",
                                "            )",
                                "   except:",
                                "      print(\"Error executing batch_writer\")"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "Runtime": "python3.7",
                "Timeout": 900,
                "MemorySize": 3008,
                "Environment" : {
                    "Variables" : {"bucket" : { "Ref" : "BucketName" }, "key" : { "Ref" : "FileName" },"table" : { "Ref" : "DynamoDBTableName" }}
                }
            }
        },

        "S3Bucket": {
            "DependsOn" : ["CsvToDDBLambdaFunction","BucketPermission"],
            "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            "Properties": {

                "BucketName": {"Ref" : "BucketName"},
                "AccessControl": "BucketOwnerFullControl",
                "NotificationConfiguration":{
                    "LambdaConfigurations":[
                        {
                            "Event":"s3:ObjectCreated:*",
                            "Function":{
                                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                    "CsvToDDBLambdaFunction",
                                    "Arn"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "BucketPermission":{
            "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
            "Properties":{
                "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "FunctionName":{"Ref" : "CsvToDDBLambdaFunction"},
                "Principal": "s3.amazonaws.com",
                "SourceAccount": {"Ref":"AWS::AccountId"}
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs" : {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーメッセージの通り

> DynamoDBTable   CREATE_FAILED   testfile already exists in stack arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-northeast-1:671527041604:stack/xxx/b4e28760-b52a-11ea-9d7b-06c1e14cac70

DynamoDB上に同名のテーブルが既に存在することが原因で、それを削除するかテーブル名を変更する必要があります。

> dynamodbtablename[test]
> ↑サンプルに合うフォーマットで作成したテーブル

CloudFormationはテーブルを作成するコードを含んでいるので、事前に作成しておくことは邪魔にしかならないということでしょう。

Comment: >>sayuri たしかに同名のスタックが既にあったために起きたエラーのようです。ありがとう。